# Procedure has to many arguments specified

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, telerik

I know that all the data types must be the same and the variables must have the same name, but from what I can tell they are all the same. I use the same parameters and variables for update and it works every time, so I am not sure why they would not be good for insert. Below are my parameters for my stored proc.

```
@Customer varchar(20),
@Cust_NAMC_ID varchar(10),
@Program varchar(10),
@PO_Type_ID varchar(10),
@Part_No varchar(20),
@Part_Name varchar(50),
@Date_Rcvd varchar(50),
@New_Price decimal (18,4),
@Tooling_Price decimal (18,4),
@RFQ_Num varchar(20),
@Eff_From varchar(50),
@Eff_To varchar(50),
@FG_Part_No varchar(20),
@FG_Part_Name varchar(50),
@Ship_From varchar(50),
@Ship_To varchar(50),
@TG_NAMC varchar(50),
@Vendor_CD int,
@PO_NUM varchar(50),
@REV_NO varchar(20),
@Buyer_Name varchar(200),
@Manager_Name varchar(200),
@BU char(2),
@SAM varchar(50),
@RFQ_To_CUST varchar(50),
@Quoted_Date varchar(50),
@PO_From_FG varchar(50),
@PO_RCVD_Date varchar(50),
@PO_Eff_Date varchar(50)
```

These are my columns:

```
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Customer" ItemStyle-CssClass="customerddl" DataField="Customer"
                    FilterControlAltText="Filter Customer" SortExpression="Customer" FilterCheckListEnableLoadOnDemand="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" GroupByExpression="Customer Group By Customer" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="125px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="lblCustomer" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Customer") %>'></telerik:RadLabel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="Update_Customer" DataSourceID="CustomerDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" DefaultMessage="-Select-" CssClass="req-field"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="Insert_Customer" DataSourceID="CustomerDataSource" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" DefaultMessage="-Select-" CssClass="req-field"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Cust_NAMC_ID" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" HeaderText="Customer NAMC">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="115px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Program" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" HeaderText="Program">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PO_Type_ID" HeaderText="CCP" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Part_No" HeaderText="Component PN" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="110px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Part_Name" HeaderText="Component Name" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="175px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Date_Rcvd" HeaderText="Date Rec'd" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="New_Price" HeaderText="New Price" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Tooling_Price" HeaderText="Tooling" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="RFQ_Num" HeaderText="Toyota Letter Reference RFQ #" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Eff_From" HeaderText="Effective From" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Eff_To" HeaderText="Effective To" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FG_Part_No" HeaderText="Finished Good PN" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FG_Part_Name" HeaderText="Finished Good Name" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Ship_From" HeaderText="Ship From" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="175px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Ship_To" HeaderText="Ship To" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="175px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TG_NAMC" HeaderText="TG NAMC" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Vendor_CD" HeaderText="TG Vendor Code" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PO_NUM" HeaderText="PO NO" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_NO" HeaderText="Rev" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Buyer_Name" HeaderText="Buyer" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="135px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Manager_Name" HeaderText="Manager" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="125px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BU" HeaderText="Business Unit" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SAM" HeaderText="SAM" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="125px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="RFQ_To_CUST" HeaderText="RFQ to Customer" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Quoted_Date" HeaderText="Quoted Date" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PO_From_FG" HeaderText="PO from FG" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PO_RCVD_Date" HeaderText="PO Received Date" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PO_Eff_Date" HeaderText="Effective Date" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

These are my insert parameters:

```
        <asp:Parameter Name="Customer" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_NAMC_ID" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Program" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Type_ID" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Part_No" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Part_Name" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Rcvd" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="New_Price" DbType="Decimal" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Tooling_Price" DbType="Decimal" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RFQ_Num" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Eff_From" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Eff_To" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FG_Part_No" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FG_Part_Name" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Ship_From" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Ship_To" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TG_NAMC" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Vendor_CD" DbType="Int32" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PO_NUM" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="REV_NO" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Buyer_Name" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Manager_Name" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BU" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SAM" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RFQ_To_CUST" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quoted_Date" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PO_From_FG" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PO_RCVD_Date" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Eff_Date" DbType="String" Direction="Input" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What database do you use? How do you call your procedure ? What is the exact error that you get ? Thanks!

Comment: @VBokšić its a sql server database, the procedure is called via a sql data source, after using the built in crud of telerik rad grid and the error is the title.

Comment: As far as I can see the parameters in stored procedure are the same as the parameters in the code. I would recommend to use SQL Profiler to see with what parameters the stored procedure is called.

Comment: @Egbert is there any documentation that you could provide on how to use this?

Comment: @Angesehen Here's a short tutorial to get started:
https://www.lifewire.com/creating-trace-with-sql-server-profiler-1019869

Comment: @Egbert so none of my stored procs show up in the profiler. The update works fine and it also never is in it.

Comment: I am losing my mind, I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on, Update uses the same parameters and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that an extra parameter was being passed in for insert that is needed for edit. I removed the value by doing this:

```
protected void grdCCPSource_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters.Remove(e.Command.Parameters["@Created_Date"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your insert sproc either run a print statement printing out all the parameter values and/or run a select statement doing the same.

eg.

```
alter insert_sproc
( 
   @Customer varchar(20),
   @Cust_NAMC_ID varchar(10),
   etc….
 )

  begin
   print 'customer parm:' + @Customer 
   print 'Cust_NAMC_ID parm:' + @Cust_NAMC_ID 
   etc..
```

Once you determine that parm values are being passed in ok, redirect your focus on the actual insert statement.

```
  insert into tableName(customer)
  select @customer

   GO
```

See what happens after your run the insert. Note any error messages, like a constraints or data type issues that may be occurring on the insert try.

Comment: The insert works fine when i execute just from SQL, so this is not going to help much I don't think.

Comment: i see, its it a permissions issue?  check your execute (insert) permissions on that sproc (and affected tables) for the user that's used in the web.config connection string.